# appendTo in jquery replace old div insted of add new one under it

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have problem with this code. I am trying to append new div (newGallery) with pictures to div (gallery) but it is still replacing old one.

Can you please advice me how to solve it? I think it has some trouble that it is inside ajax funcion. I am using jquery v3.5.1.

```
menu.on('click', 'a', function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var a = $(this),
        li = a.parent(),
        href = a.attr('href'),
        loadingImg = $('<img>', {src: 'img/5.svg', class: 'loading-img'}),
        id = '#' + href.slice(0, -5),
        isLoaded = gallery.find(id),
        currentGallery = gallery.find('.gallery-set'),
        galleries = $('.gallery-set');

    if (li.hasClass('selected')) return;

    li.addClass('selected')
      .siblings().removeClass('selected');
    //zobrazenie loading ikony pokial sa obsah nenacita
    gallery.html(loadingImg).show();
    gallery.find('div').fadeOut();

    if ( galleries.attr("id") == id ) {
        currentGallery.hide();
        gallery.find(id).fadeIn();

    } else {
        loadNewGallery(href);
    };

    function loadNewGallery (href) {
        var gallery = $('.gallery');

        $.ajax({
            url: href,
            data: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html',
        // ak sa data nacitaju vykona sa funkcia v done
        }).done( function( data ) {
            var newGallery = $(data).find('.gallery-set');

                //nacitany kus stranky cez ajax sa vlozi do gallery natrvalo
                newGallery.appendTo(gallery);

        // ak sa data nenacitaju vykona sa funkcia vo fail
        }).fail( function() {
            // sprava o zlyhani prenosu
            var msg = $('<div>',{class: 'msg-fail'}),
                msgText = 'Je nám ľúto, danú stránku sa nepodarilo zobraziť',
                msgFail = msg.html(msgText);

            gallery.html(msgFail);
        // aj ked sa data nacitaju alebo nenacitaju vykona sa funkcia v always
        }).always(function() {
            // skrytie loading ikonky
            loadingImg.hide();
        });
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way...

```
const gallery = $('.gallery');

function loadNewGallery(href) {
  $.ajax({
    url: href,
    data: 'GET',
    dataType: 'html',
    // ak sa data nacitaju vykona sa funkcia v done
  }).done(function(data) {
    var newGallery = $(data).find('.gallery-set');

    //nacitany kus stranky cez ajax sa vlozi do gallery natrvalo
    newGallery.appendTo(gallery);

    // ak sa data nenacitaju vykona sa funkcia vo fail
  }).fail(function() {
    // sprava o zlyhani prenosu
    var msg = $('<div>', {
        class: 'msg-fail'
      }),
      msgText = 'Je nám ľúto, danú stránku sa nepodarilo zobraziť',
      msgFail = msg.html(msgText);

    gallery.html(msgFail);
    // aj ked sa data nacitaju alebo nenacitaju vykona sa funkcia v always
  }).always(function() {
    // skrytie loading ikonky
    loadingImg.hide();
  });
};


menu.on('click', 'a', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var a = $(this),
    li = a.parent(),
    href = a.attr('href'),
    loadingImg = $('<img>', {
      src: 'img/5.svg',
      class: 'loading-img'
    }),
    id = '#' + href.slice(0, -5),
    isLoaded = gallery.find(id),
    currentGallery = gallery.find('.gallery-set'),
    galleries = $('.gallery-set');

  if (li.hasClass('selected')) return;

  li.addClass('selected')
    .siblings().removeClass('selected');
  //zobrazenie loading ikony pokial sa obsah nenacita
  gallery.html(loadingImg).show();
  gallery.find('div').fadeOut();

  if (galleries.attr("id") == id) {
    currentGallery.hide();
    gallery.find(id).fadeIn();

  } else {
    loadNewGallery(href);
  };


});
```

Comment: It would be good if you can explain your answer more . i.e : what changes you made , why above code will work ...etc

Comment: @Swati `gallery` is used before being defined in the script snippet present in the question. I simply used a `const` for the `gallery` element, removed the function out of the `click` event... and that is all. The way the code is written `newGallery` should be appended to `gallery`. My main objection is on `fail` where the message completely changes the `innerHTML` of `gallery` element.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but it does not work for me. It is still overwritting one div element inside gallery.

Comment: @user2623507 could you also add the typical HTML that is returned in your ajax call. As i see you get the new gallery-set from the data returned from your ajax call. In addition some more code to help re-create the issue would be ideal (e.g. add the HTML of gallery).

Comment: @PeterDarmis I already found problem. This commad made troubles gallery.html(loadingImg).show(); when I replace html() for appendTo it is ok. Thanks all for help.